# How does the keyword "this" work with arrow functions?

Tags: javascript

I know arrow functions do not have their own "this", the borrow the "this" of their enclosing lexical scope.

```
const person = {
    points: 23,
    score: () => {
      this.points++;
  }
};
```

Why does the `person.score` give me undefined, as an arrow function, it should have access to this?

Comment: In this example, the `this` gets the global scope which is equal to the `window` object it the `person` object not within any other scoped block. If you want to get the `person` object's reference then you have to write `score: function() {}`.

Comment: Because it is a function and not returning anything.

Answer (score 2):

Arrow function do not have their own this function. Because the arrow function doesn't have a `this` associated with it, it uses the parent's `this`.

In your example, this inside person will point to parent and the parent of the person object is Window. So, the `this` points to enclosing scope and not the person object. In your case , this is bound to global object. You can see the contents of `this` printed below (the Window object).

```js
const person1 = {
  points: 23,
  score: function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
};
// this in score function will point to person1
person1.score();

const person2 = {
  points: 23,
  score: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
};
// here, this will point to global object       
person2.score();
```